# Ayuda con arraylist ,Modificar elementos?

Tags: java, arraylist

Buenas no entiendo como modifico los datos ya asignados, se que tendría que utilizar los métodos set, pero no logro hacerlo.

```
 String array[][]= new String [list.size()][6];

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            array[i][0] = list.get(i).getId();
            array[i][1] = list.get(i).getNombre();
            array[i][2] = list.get(i).getApellido();
            array[i][3] = list.get(i).getEdad();
            array[i][4] = list.get(i).getDireccion();
            array[i][5] = list.get(i).getTelefono();
        }
```

Comment: que valores tiene list? agrega el objeto que almacena

Comment: Un objeto de tipo paciente, con sus respectivos atributos

Comment: ¿Pero te da algún error?

Comment: Este código vendría siendo guardar, lo que no logro hacer es el modificar los atributos de ese objeto.  Alguna idea de tu parte me serviria

Comment: Es como has dicho tu, pero sin ver más código es difícil ayudarte. Se haría con los set que has creado en el objeto paciente. Para modificar el nombre del primer elemento de la lista sería: list.get(i).setNombre("Perico de los palotes"); Lo mismo para el resto de los campos pero lo dicho, tienes que hacerlos como lo hayas declarado en tu objeto paciente.

Answer (score 2):

Debes hacer uso de los Setters. He hecho un ejemplo completo bien comentado para que puedas entender cómo se usan y todo lo que puedes hacer con ellos.

Clase Paciente:

```
public class Paciente {

    // Variables
    private int Id;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private int edad;
    private String direccion;
    private int telefono;

    // Constructor
    public Paciente(int id, String nombre, String apellido, int edad, String direccion, int telefono) {
        super();
        Id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    // Getters
    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public int getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

}
```

Clase Ejemplo (con el método "main"):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Ejemplo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Crear pacientes
        Paciente paciente1 = new Paciente(1, "Ejemplo1", "Ejemplo", 21, "Ejemplo", 5558888);
        Paciente paciente2 = new Paciente(2, "Ejemplo2", "Ejemplo", 22, "Ejemplo", 5558888);
        Paciente paciente3 = new Paciente(3, "Ejemplo3", "Ejemplo", 23, "Ejemplo", 5558888);
        Paciente paciente4 = new Paciente(4, "Ejemplo4", "Ejemplo", 24, "Ejemplo", 5558888);
        Paciente paciente5 = new Paciente(5, "Ejemplo5", "Ejemplo", 25, "Ejemplo", 5558888);
        Paciente paciente6 = new Paciente(6, "Ejemplo6", "Ejemplo", 26, "Ejemplo", 5558888);

        // Agregar pacientes a una lista
        List<Paciente> pacientes = new ArrayList<Paciente>();
        pacientes.add(paciente1);
        pacientes.add(paciente2);
        pacientes.add(paciente3);
        pacientes.add(paciente4);
        pacientes.add(paciente5);
        pacientes.add(paciente6);

        // Imprimir datos de los pacientes (usando un loop For-each introducido en "Java 8")
        System.out.println("Todos los pacientes:");
        for (Paciente pacienteActual : pacientes) {
            System.out.println(pacienteActual.getId() + ", " + 
                    pacienteActual.getNombre() + ", " + 
                    pacienteActual.getApellido() + ", " + 
                    pacienteActual.getEdad() + ", " + 
                    pacienteActual.getDireccion() + ", " + 
                    pacienteActual.getTelefono());
        }

        // Obtener los datos del paciente con el ID = 4
        System.out.println("\nPaciente con el ID = 4:");
        System.out.println(pacientes.get(3).getId() + ", " +
                pacientes.get(3).getNombre() + ", " +
                pacientes.get(3).getApellido() + ", " + 
                pacientes.get(3).getEdad() + ", " + 
                pacientes.get(3).getDireccion() + ", " + 
                pacientes.get(3).getTelefono());

        // Modificar el nombre del paciente con el ID = 2 e imprimirlo
        System.out.println("\nNombre nuevo del paciente con el ID = 2:");
        pacientes.get(1).setNombre("Nuevo nombre");
        System.out.println(pacientes.get(1).getId() + ", " + pacientes.get(1).getNombre());

        // Modificando los datos de todos los pacientes
        for (Paciente pacienteActual : pacientes) {
            pacienteActual.setId(11);
            pacienteActual.setNombre("Otro1");
            pacienteActual.setApellido("Otro");
            pacienteActual.setEdad(51);
            pacienteActual.setDireccion("Nueva");
            pacienteActual.setTelefono(123456);
        }

        // Vaciar la lista de pacientes
        pacientes.clear();
        System.out.println("\nTamaño de la lista: " + pacientes.size());
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes una lista que contiene varios objetos, puedes acceder a el objeto definido en la lista mediante el indice y modificar sus propiedades mediante los métodos setter.

Por ejemplo si deseas el 3 elemento de la lista (indice 2, ya que se inicia en 0), y deseas modificar por ejemplo las propiedades Nombre y Apellido lo realizarías de esta forma:

```
list.get(2).setNombre("Dan");
list.get(2).getApellido("Server");
```

de esta forma modificarias las propiedades de ese objeto en la lista.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, intentare con esas instrucciones avanzar...

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que utilizar los setters:

```
array[i][0] = list.get(i).setId(2);
array[i][1] = list.get(i).setNombre("John Doe");
```

Las listas están compuestas de objetos. Si la clase de los objetos de los que tu lista está compuesta no tiene los setters que necesitas no podrás llamarlos.

Resumen: Implementa los setters en la clase Persona o como se llame la clase que utiliza tu lista.